# Program cannot deserialize borsch serialized instruction from typescript client

Tags: rust, account, web3.js, borsh, serialization

I am trying to write a client code in typescript for a contract written in vanilla rust.  I am unable to serialize an instruction such that it can be deserialized by the program

```
#[derive(Debug, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]

pub enum WalletInstruction {
    /// Initialize a Personal Savings Wallet
    ///
    /// Passed accounts:
    ///
    /// (1) Wallet account
    /// (2) Vault accounts
    /// (3) Authority
    /// (4) Rent sysvar
    /// (5) System program
    Initialize,
    /// Deposit
    ///
    /// Passed accounts:
    ///
    /// (1) Wallet account
    /// (2) Vault accounts
    /// (3) Money Source
    Deposit { amount: u64 },
    /// Withdraw from Wallet
    ///
    /// Passed accounts:
    ///
    /// (1) Wallet account
    /// (2) Vault accounts
    /// (3) Authority
    /// (4) Target Wallet account
    Withdraw { amount: u64 },
}

pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    mut instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    match WalletInstruction::deserialize(&mut instruction_data)? {
        WalletInstruction::Initialize => initialize(program_id, accounts),
        WalletInstruction::Deposit { amount } => deposit(program_id, accounts, amount),
        WalletInstruction::Withdraw { amount } => withdraw(program_id, accounts, amount),
    }
}
```

In my client side, I have this

```
class Assignable {
    constructor(properties) {
        Object.keys(properties).map((key) => {
            return (this[key] = properties[key]);
        });
    };
};

class Deposit extends Assignable {
    toBuffer() {
        return Buffer.from(borsh.serialize(DepositSchema, this));
    }
}

const DepositSchema = new Map([
    [
        Deposit, {
            kind: 'struct',
            fields: [
                ['amount', 'u8'],
            ]
        }
    ]
]);


const DepositInstructionData = new Deposit({
    amount: deposit_amount,
})
let ix = new TransactionInstruction({
    keys:[
        {pubkey: wallet_adddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},// Wallet Account
        {pubkey: vault_adddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},// Vault Account
        {pubkey: rich_boi.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true},// Rich Boi Account
        {pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false}// System Program
    ],
    programId: program.publicKey,
    data: DepositInstructionData.toBuffer(),
})
```

When i execute the transaction, i am getting this error

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First correct your schema declaration:

```
// Instruction variant indexes
enum InstructionVariant {
    InitializeAccount = 0,
    Deposit,
    Withdraw,
}

const DepositSchema = new Map([
    [
        Deposit, {
            kind: 'struct',
            fields: [
                ['id', 'u8'],   // This is for the instruction invariant
                ['amount', 'u64'],
            ]
        }
    ]
]);
```

Then serialize a meaningful instance of the Deposit, for example:

```
    // Construct the payload
    const deposit = new Deposit({
        id: InstructionVariant.Deposit,
        amount: 200,
    });

    // Serialize the payload
    const depositSerBuf = Buffer.from(serialize(DepositSchema, deposit));
```

Construct your transaction:

```
let ix = new TransactionInstruction({
    keys:[
        {pubkey: wallet_adddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},// Wallet Account
        {pubkey: vault_adddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},// Vault Account
        {pubkey: rich_boi.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true},// Rich Boi Account
        {pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false}// System Program
    ],
    programId: program.publicKey,
    data: depositSerBuf,
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`amount` is declared as `u64` in the Rust program, but only `u8` on the client side schema. All type declarations must match in both size and layout on both sides

Comment: Isn't the index of the instruction also missing from this code?

Comment: well... the entire transaction construction and broadcast is missing, yet they got a simulation error. presumably there's more missing :shrug:

Answer (score 2):

this is another solution that worked for me

```
function DepositInstructionData(deposit_amount): Buffer {
    const dataLayout = BufferLayout.struct([
        BufferLayout.u8('instruction'),
        BufferLayout.nu64('amount'),
      ]);

      const data = Buffer.alloc(dataLayout.span);
      dataLayout.encode({
        instruction: 1,
        amount: deposit_amount,
      }, data);
    
      return data;
}
   
let deposit_amount = 200;
let ix = new TransactionInstruction({
            keys:[
                {pubkey: wallet_adddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},// Wallet Account
                {pubkey: vault_adddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},// Vault Account
                {pubkey: rich_boi.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true},// Rich Boi Account
                {pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false}// System Program
            ],
            programId: program.publicKey,
            data: DepositInstructionData(deposit_amount),
        })
```